# How to make conda correctly detect my cuda version?

Tags: conda

I once installed cuda 11.1 on my windows but have already uninstalled it along with all related packages. Now I have created a new conda env and installed cudatoolkit=10.0, but somehow conda still detects that my cuda version is 11.1 and always throws errors like this:

```
The following specifications were found to be incompatible with your system:

  - feature:/win-64::__cuda==11.1=0
  - feature:|@/win-64::__cuda==11.1=0
```

when I'm trying to install some packages.

How can I remove the cuda 11.1 completely or just make conda point to the correct cuda version in my conda env?